# Send email to all email address from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, email

I am trying to send email to All users from Mysql Database. For this I have written below Code, but it is sending email to First record only. What's wrong I am doing. I need to send email to all users.

```
if ($_POST['do'] == 'mail') {


$result = $db->query("SELECT email FROM members WHERE status='Active'");

$input="This is a text message";

       $userdetails = $db->fetch_array($result);

       $emails = implode(",", $userdetails);

        $message = $input;
        $mail = new mail();
        $mail->setFrom($settings['email_support'], $input->pc['name']);
        $mail->addTo($emails);
        $mail->setSubject('subject text!');
        $mail->setBodyText($message);
        $mail->send();
}
```

Comment: because you are only fetching 1 row ... perhaps you want a loop to iterate all the rows

Comment: how can i iterate a loop with this?

Comment: You don't want to put all these email addresses together in the mailto: field. That way everyone who receives the email can see all other email addresses you used. Either send individual emails, which is what the mailserver does anyway, or use the BCC field.

Comment: **DO NOT SEND MASS EMAIL WITH ALL RECIPIENTS IN THE SUBJECT LINE**. Every recipient can read that and will now have a copy of your mailing list. Use BCC: if possible. Send individual emails if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code perfect. It can be possible you are fetching only 1 row. If not, then try this it will help you.

```
if ($_POST['do'] == 'mail') {
    $result = $db->query("SELECT email FROM members WHERE status='Active'");
    $input = "This is a text message";
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $message = $input;
        $mail = new mail();
        $mail->setFrom($settings['email_support'], $input->pc['name']);
        $mail->addTo($row['email']);
        $mail->setSubject('subject text!');
        $mail->setBodyText($message);
        $mail->send();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried still same, sending only to first record

Comment: did you have checked the num of rows count?

Comment: Did u mean in data table ? Yes 3000+ rows